# validation username and password

Tags: php, html

This is my php validtion code!

```
   <?php        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------>PHP VALIDATION
                $user="";
                $pass="";
                $nameErr="";
                $passErr="";
                //$pattern='/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_ ]*$/';
                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
                {
                    if(empty($_POST['uname']))
                    {
                        $nameErr='Enter Your Name!';
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $user = test_input($_POST['uname']);
                        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/',$user))
                            {
                                $nameErr=' Re-Enter Your Name! Format Inccorrect!( only alpha, numbers,@_ are allowed)';
                            }
                    }
                    if(empty($_POST['pas']))
                    {
                        $passErr='Enter Your Password!';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $user = test_input($_POST['pas']);
                        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/',$pass))
                        {
                            $passErr='Invalid Format! Re-Enter Password!';
                        }
                    }   
                }



            function test_input($data)
            {
                 $data = trim($data);
                 $data = stripslashes($data);
                 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                 return $data;
            }
                ?>

HTML:
<html>
<body>
<div id='shw'><?php echo $user;?></div>
                <fieldset id='fld'>
                    <form method='post' name='f1' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>'>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    User Name:<input type='text' id='uname' name='uname' class='uname' placeholder='USERNAME' autocomplete='off' autofocus maxlength='25'><span class='error'>*</span>
                                    Password:<input type='password' id='pass' class='pass' name='pas' placeholder='PASSWORD' autocomplete='off'>
                                            <input type='submit' name='submit' id='loggin' value='LOGIN' class='login' onclick='val()'>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            <div class='errormsg' id='errmsg'><?php echo $nameErr;?></div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

iam having problm in validation i want to show user name after submit.
problem is that my username if else is running good but it skips the password part. iwant that it shud also validate pass field then only shows the username!
please help!

Comment: Add an `var_dump($_POST);` at the beginning of the checks to see what's sended. Just a tip, name function for what they do, because test_input does no testing ;)

Comment: You mix post and defined variables, like asking for empty($_POST['pas']) , then defining that with $user = test_input($_POST['pas']); but checking $pass in preg_match, and $pass is defined as non value "" on top.

Comment: There is no need to sanitize a password, since you want to use an appropriate hash function to store it anyway, see the function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: Why are you restricting password format?

Answer (score 1):

`$user = test_input($_POST['pas']);` should be `$pass = test_input($_POST['pas']);`

Your current code set $user in you first `if..else` block, it's not that PHP skips your second `if...else` block, it's just that no matter what this block will do, ûser is already set.
If you don't want to display $user if password is invalid, just set $user later in you code:
    $nameErr = null;
    $passErr = null;

```
if (empty($_POST['uname'])) {
    $nameErr = 'Enter Your Name!';
} else {
    $userTest = test_input($_POST['uname']);

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/', $userTest)) {
        $nameErr = ' Re-Enter Your Name! Format Inccorrect! (only alpha, numbers, @_ are allowed)';
    } else {
        $valid++;
    }
}
if (empty($_POST['pas'])) {
    $passErr = 'Enter Your Password!';
} else {
    $pass = test_input($_POST['pas']);

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/', $pass)) {
        $passErr = 'Invalid Format! Re-Enter Password!';
    } else {
        $valid++;
    }
}

if (is_null($nameErr) && is_null($passErr)) {
    $user = $_POST['uname']
}
```

Here, I just check if $nameErr and $passErr are still null at the end of your tests. If both are null, then you can set $user, since no error has been detected.

Comment: @evuez: Should you edit some other questions, please review the entire post instead of just separating the code blocks. A few other revisions were still left open. I've already corrected them for now. Thx!